# How do I prevent an event from being sent when syncing players?

Tags: javascript, sockets, synchronization

I'm working on a multi-user video viewing application that requires synchronizing the playback time for all users in a room. To achieve this, I'm using pause and play events and sending the time to the server whenever someone presses play or pause. The server then broadcasts the time to all users in the room.

However, I'm encountering an issue where sometimes the client sends duplicate events to the server, causing the events to affect the sender's playback as well as all other users in the room. This unintended behavior disrupts the synchronization.

[Here's how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLp8j.png)

- On the left is the client that sends pause and play events.
- On the right is another user who receives the events.

The desired outcome is that the left client does not receive its own events because it only needs to act upon events received from other users.

Here's the code I've written:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let socketio = io();
    let date = new Date();
    let userId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
    console.log(userId)

    let player = new Playerjs({
        id: "player",
        file: JSON.parse($("#player").attr("data-links"))
    });

    cloneChatToOverlay();

    let isInitialPlay = true,
        isInitialPause = true,
        isInitialSeek = true;

    const playerFrame = $("#player"),
          messagesBox = $(".chat-box .messages"),
          messagesScroll = $(".chat-box"),
          chatInputs = $(".chat-inputs");

    socketio.on("client_play", (data) => {
        isInitialPlay = false;
        if (data.user !== userId) {
            if (Math.abs(data.time - player.api("time")) > 1) {
                isInitialSeek = false;
                player.api("seek", data.time);
                console.log("Socket seek: ", data.user);
                isInitialSeek = true;
            }
            if (!player.api("playing")) {
                player.api("play");
                console.log("Socket play: ", data.user);
            }
        }
        isInitialPlay = true;
    });

    socketio.on("client_pause", (data) => {
        isInitialPause = false;
        if (data.user !== userId) {
            if (player.api("playing")) {
                player.api("pause");
                console.log("Socket pause: ", data.user);
            }
        }
        isInitialPause = true;
    });

    socketio.on("client_seek", (data) => {
        player.api("seek", data.time);
    });

    playerFrame.on("play", (event) => {
        if (isInitialPlay) {
            socketio.emit("server_play", { time: player.api("time"), user: userId });
        } else {
            isInitialPlay = true;
        }
    });

    playerFrame.on("pause", (event) => {
        if (isInitialPause) {
            socketio.emit("server_pause", { user: userId });
        } else {
            isInitialPause = true;
        }
    });

    playerFrame.on("seek", (event) => {
        if (isInitialSeek) {
            socketio.emit("server_seek", { time: player.api("time") });
        } else {
            isInitialSeek = true;
        }
    });
});
```

I suspect that the issue lies in the event handling logic, possibly due to improper conditions or event listeners. How can I modify the code to ensure that the client doesn't process its own events and maintain proper synchronization among all users in the room?